# PHP How to get numbers and string separated by 'space-space' using regEXP

Tags: php, regex

Please I have the flowing string :

```
$str = 'blabla-blabla - 12345, blobl-ooo - 54123, hihihi - 98745';
```

I want to get in an array **blabla-blabla - 12345** and **blobl-ooo - 54123** and **hihihi - 98745**

To do that I'm thinking to use REGEXP so I've tried :

```
preg_match_all("/\b[\p{L}'-]+|[a-z]+\b/u", $str, $all);
```

but this get only the string part and not the numbers.

Please any advice masters ?

PS : I can't use list and explode because I don't know the number of elements in my string.

Comment: Why can't you explode on ',' without using list ?

Comment: @magnetik that should be an answer

Comment: The number of elements in this example is 3. But it could be 4 or 5, so I don't know how many variables should I pass to list !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your regex, try:

```
preg_match_all('/([\w\-]+ \- \d+),?/u', $str, $all);
```

*\w* deals for all letters or digits, and the *\d* for all digits.

Otherwise, even if you do not know the size of your string, you can use explode:

```
$parts = explode(', ', $str);
foreach($parts as $part) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you can't use `explode` to split on commas.  You don't need to know the number of elements to do that.  However, a regex like this should work:

```
"/[\w\-]+ \- \d+/"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [preg_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) function for it..

```
str = 'blabla-blabla - 12345, blobl-ooo - 54123, hihihi - 98745'; 
$result=preg_split('/,/',$str);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
```

Output
 Array
(
    [0] => blabla-blabla - 12345
    [1](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) =>  blobl-ooo - 54123
    [2](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Lt64re) =>  hihihi - 98745
)

[DEMO](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Lt64re)